Apache beam streaming process with time base windows
I have a dataflow pipeline that reads messages from kafka, process them, and insert them into bigquery.
I want that the processing / bigquery insertion will happen in time based batches, so that on every (1 minute) interval, all messages that was read from kafka in that interval will be processed into bigquery.
I was trying to follow the docs example and made the below pipeline:
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms import window

beam_options = SetupOptions(beam_args, streaming=True)
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:

    # read Kafka events
    raw = (
        pipeline
        | "read kafka events" >> kafkaio.KafkaConsume(consumer_config=kafka_config)
        | "extract msg" >> (beam.Map(lambda x: x[1])).with_output_types(str)
    )

    debug1 = (raw | "debug1" >> beam.Map(lambda x: print(f"debug1: {type(x)}, {x}")))

    windows = (raw | 'apply window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60)))

    debug2 = (windows | "debug2" >> beam.Map(lambda x: print(f"debug2: {type(x)}, {x}")))

But when I run it, I see that the two debug steps, debug1 and debug2, run immediately one after the other, indicating that the windowing didn't really happen.
I think I'm missing something basic.
In the documentation here, the example pipeline has a GroupByKey step. Maybe it is necessary when using time based windows, although I dont really need to group on my use case.
Thanks in advance

On its own, windowing into something in Beam does not do anything. The windowing is not applied, unless you implement also a grouping transform. See the programming guide for details.

I believe you need to add triggering to your code like:
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    raw = (
        pipeline
        | "read kafka events" >> kafkaio.KafkaConsume(consumer_config=kafka_config)
        | "extract msg" >> (beam.Map(lambda x: x[1])).with_output_types(str)
    )

    debug1 = raw | "debug1" >> beam.Map(lambda x: print(f"debug1: {type(x)}, {x}"))

    windows = (
        raw
        | 'apply window' >> beam.WindowInto(
            window.FixedWindows(60),
            trigger=beam.trigger.AfterProcessingTime(60),  
            accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING  
        )
    )

    debug2 = windows | "debug2" >> beam.Map(lambda x: print(f"debug2: {type(x)}, {x}"))


You are correct, applied Windowing only impacts how grouping (primarily GroupByKey, but also other forms of aggregation like combines and state and joining and side inputs) is performed. Generally data flow through the pipeline as fast as possible, and only when multiple elements need to be co-located are any elements buffered to wait until all the other "matching" elements have also arrived.
You could introduce some fake keys and do a GBK on that. Note also that most sinks, including writing to BigQuery, do some amount of batching internally.
